# ArrayStoreException When Converting from list of 1D arrays to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, converters

I'm getting a java.lang.ArrayStoreException error with the following method:

```
public static int[][] getData(String path) throws IOException
    {
        // Read all
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
        List<String []> list = csvReader.readAll();
        csvReader.close();

        // Convert to 2D array
        int[][] dataArr=list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<3; x++)
            {


System.out.print(dataArr[i][x]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return dataArr;
}
```

It references the line under '//convert to 2D array' as the problem, I've tried a variety of ways that I've seen in other questions to make this work, but to no avail!
The code references a CSV file in *path* and then fills in a 2D array with the values. If there is an easier way than using CSVReader that anyone knows of I'd love to see it! I found this code here and I've seen several other posts about it, but this seems to be the easiest and I don't think that it's leading to the problem.

Thank's so much in advance.

Comment: A simple typographical error.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Since it's so simple, why don't you give a constructive reply?

Comment: @avojak How will OP benefit from me reiterating what 3 answers already say? Not to mention [multiple related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow+ArrayStoreException&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) already have answers that sum up what has been said below. I didn't mean *simple* in a negative way, I just added a comment with which close flag I was raising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line:

```
int[][] dataArr=list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);
```

You're are trying to store a `String[]` in an `int[][]`, which is not allowed. And since arrays check the type of it's components at runtime, you get an exception.

---

If you want to convert a `List<String[]>` to `int[][]` you're going to have to do it manually:

```
int[][] dataArr = new int[list.size()][];

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    dataArr[i] = new int[list.get(i).length];
    for(int j = 0; j < dataArr[i].length; j++) {
        dataArr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i)[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a new error now, Number Format Exception, in the 'dataArr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i)[j]);' line.

Comment: @WilliamJestes That means that your input string is not a valid ```Integer```. e.g. if the String is ```"not a number"``` instead of something like ```"15"```, this exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your initial response, I realized that the input file contained strings and I shouldn't have been trying to create an integer double array.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your List of Strings to a String[][]:

```
// Convert to 2D array
String[][] dataArr=list.toArray(new String[0][0]);
```

Comment: What if OP needs the an `int[][]` like the code shows, and not `String[][]` as you suggest?

Comment: Then he has to somehow convert the String[] to int[] :
   list.stream().map(stringArray -> createIntArrayFromString(stringArray));

Answer (score 1):

Notice the documentation for the `.toArray()` method:

> **Throws**: **ArrayStoreException** - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the
>   runtime type of every element in this list

In your case, the specified array is of type `int[]`, and that is not a supertype of the type of each element in the list, which is `String[]`.

The fix can depend on what type of array you need. If you need an `int[][]` from the Strings, you'll need to iterate and build out the `int[][]`. If a `String[][]` is sufficient, then you can instead give a new `String[][]` to the `.toArray()` method.